# TLS1.3 encrypted handshake

Tags: tls, transport-security

I read that TLS 1.3 supports encrypted handshake. Is it achieved using encrypted_extensions?

Does it mean that the records which contains handshake messages are encrypted/protected from the point of view of record-protocol?

Or

Does it mean that the handshake protocol itself encrypts its message payload and records are plain text from record-protocol perspective?

Comment: The record layer takes care of the encryption of the late part of the handshake.

Comment: Refer https://8gwifi.org/docs/tlsv13.jsp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TLS 1.3, all messages after `ServerHello` are encrypted. This encryption happens before `EncryptedExtensions` is sent. The traffic keys [protect the record layer payload;](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-5.2) they transform `TLSPlaintext` structs into `TLSCiphertext` structs.

During the handshake, the following messages are transmitted:

- Client $\rightarrow$ Server: `ClientHello` (generate client nonce)
- Client $\rightarrow$ Server: `ClientKeyShare` (generate ephemeral Diffie-Hellman parameter $X = g^x$)
- Server $\rightarrow$ Client: `ServerHello` (generate server nonce)
- Server $\rightarrow$ Client: `ServerKeyShare` (generate ephemeral Diffie-Hellman parameter $Y = g^y$)

At this point, both Client and Server can calculate the pre-master secret $g^{xy}$, and this is part of what goes into a PRF to derive a handshake master secret (HMS). Then you derive a handshake secret traffic key $t_{hs}$, which depends on HMS and the nonces.

The `EncryptedExtensions` message is [the first one sent after $t_{hs}$ is generated.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-4.3.1) This and the rest of the handshake messages (like `ClientCertificateVerify`, `ServerFinshed`, etc.) are encrypted with $t_{hs}$. See how the keys are computed [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-7.3).

You can see [sample handshake traces here.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-vectors-00) (Since TLS 1.3 is still in draft form, this will be obsoleted soon.)

Comment: You may want to link to the relevant sections of the current drafts as well (and not just the test vectors): [Section 5.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-5.2) for the statement that the traffic keys protect the record layer payload. [Section 4.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-4.3.1) for the encrypted extensions and the note that it uses the traffic keys as well and [Section 7.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-20#section-7.3) for the computation and usage of the traffic keys.